# HowTo deploy all files of .NET Compact Framework Application (incl. Subfolders)?

Tags: deployment, frameworks, compact-framework

I have a .NET Compact Framework Application which has subfolders containig some files.

For these files Build Action" is set to "Content" and "Copy to Output folder" is set to "Copy Always".

If i build the project, i can see the subfolders containig the files in the Debug/Release folder, but after a Deploy only the files from root Debug/Release-folder gets copied to the device; the subfolders aren't on the device.

Found that the problem exists, when i reference a project (dll-project) containing a subfolder: this subfolder is in the Debug/Release-folder of the main program, but not on the device (a main program containing a subfolder works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the referenced project to deploy and set it's deploy folder to match that of the consuming EXE's deploy folder.

Comment: Thanks it works - I thinked that subfolders in a referenced project get deployed automatically